# Using gulp.src(xyz).pipe(gulp.dest(xyz)); Facing Issues, Why not working for me?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Following code, tried with both ./ as src and dest. Gave security administration full rights to folders, just in case if there was any issue.

So whenever I change styles.css from the styles folder, the code runs good on gulp watch and detects change too. It does run styles command on file change too. But then no folders are created in my dest folder.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('styles' , function() {
  return gulp.src('/app/assets/styles/styles.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/app/styles.css'));
});



gulp.task('watch',function(){

    gulp.watch('./app/assets/styles/styles.css', 
    function() {
        gulp.start('styles');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a duplicate but I can't find it, so...  gulp.dest() takes a folder only, not a file.  It probably is creating a folder, it is just called styles.css!  You probably want gulp.dest('./app').

Comment: @Mark I tried searching for an answer for quite a few minutes at SO. Then eventually I posted the question here. Thanks for always helping out. I've replied to your answer.

Comment: No problem, I just know I have seen it recently but I can't find it now.

Comment: @Mark I agree with you, it's always much better to find from current resources. In fact, I did Google it and found a lot of answers. But all of them were too complex for me to understand the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp.dest()` takes a folder only, not a file. It probably is creating a folder, it is just called `styles.css`! Look under that for your file styles.css.

You probably want gulp.dest('./app').  the file name will be retained automatically.

I would also simplify to the below.  gulp.start is not really documented.

```
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch('./app/assets/styles/styles.css', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('styles' , function() {
   //  added the . before /app here and in dest
  return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
});
```

Comment: That's very informative to know it takes folder only, thank you Mark. I tried that way too though, it isn't creating the file. So I tried to make the first step work, to proceed further with Sass or PostCSS and more. But it's strange that even after providing a folder name to gulp.dest with or without a ./ doesn't work. What I maybe doing wrong?

Comment: So if you just run "gulp styles" and using gulp.dest('./app') it doesn't move the styles.css into the app folder? And no error messages?  And see other edits I made.

Comment: Exactly, no errors. It just starts and finishes in no time on typing "gulp styles". To further add, on doing "gulp watch" too, it does trigger "styles" correctly and shows a console message if I type in one. I have used your updated code to cross-check any mistake and also edited my code by adding a ./ again as I understand without a dot, paths doesn't work.

Comment: After 9 hours, found the problem. It all works now! So the problem was, the directory app folder was in had numerous spaces. So the name was something like "XYZ - this is [folder]" and it was pretty long too. Although, this doesn't make sense and script should have worked because my gulp installations weren't in that folder directly. But i hope this can save someone's day! @Mark, thanks again friend!